# Is there a simple fix to using "\hypertarget" inside thmtools's "restatable"?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, thmtools, hypertarget

Is it possible to use `\hypertarget` inside `restatable`? The command `\hypertarget` is from package [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en), and `restatable` is from package[`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools). The issue is that if the restatable is called, it seems to try to recreate the earlier hypertarget's destination, and with the same identifier:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{thm:\040made-up-theorem-subpart}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.30 \MadeUpTheorem*
                     [3] (./output.aux)
```

- There seems to be *no* adverse effects ***afaict***, since "duplicate ignored" is exactly the desired behavior. But I wonder, is there a better approach that avoids the problem but retains the same functionality?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter, style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem,theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter 1}

\section{Test section 1}
In the next section, we we'll state a made-up theorem. Notice, in particular, the subpart \hyperlink{thm: made-up-theorem-subpart}{there}. Here...

\section{Test section 2}

We are ready to state the made-up theorem:
\begin{restatable}[Made-Up theorem]{theorem}{MadeUpTheorem} %%%% creating an instance of restatable
    Made-up assumptions are listed here.
    {\hypertarget{thm: made-up-theorem-subpart}{}} %%%% referencing a sub-part of madeuptheorem.
    \[ X = 3AB \tag{*}\]
    This is a made-up theorem.
\end{restatable}

\chapter{Test chapter two}

Recall the following made-up theorem:

\MadeUpTheorem* %%%%madeuptheorem is recalled, creating the duplicate destination

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: Untested, but perhaps something like `\newcommand*{\myhypertarget}{\hypertarget{thm:made-up-theorem-subpart}{}\let\myhypertarget\relax}` would work? Not very convenient tough, if you have many instances...

Comment: @gusbrs I currently have three or four instances, so it wouldn't be the worst idea. However, as stated the idea appears to not work. It gives `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{thm:made-up-theorem-subpart}) has been already used, duplicate ignored <argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box                                                    \_`. Additionally, the referencing hyperlink no longer works (it worked before).

Comment: Well, I don't really know how the `restate` environment is setup, it was just an idea. But, sorry, I have no other.

Comment: @gusbrs No worries. Thank you for the attempted solution.

Comment: why do you use hypertarget at all? the theorem should already have an anchor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You mean set a `\label` and then refer with `\hyperref[label]{}`? Sounds good.  :-)

Comment: @LinearChristmas Listen to Ulrike, it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The actual restatable theorem is somewhat long, consisting of several subparts. One part is an equation inside the restatable instance. The goal is to have the hyperlink refer directly to this subpart of the restatable. I hope this makes sense :).

Comment: surround the target with `\ifthmt@thisistheone` ... `\fi`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried the following: `\makeatletter
    \ifthmt@thisistheone
    \hypertarget{thm: made-up-theorem-subpart}{}\fi
    \makeatother`. It does not seem to work. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: the \makeatletter must be outside the restatable.

Comment: The simple solutionj is to NOT use the same anchor name used by \label (which you can read in the aux file).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works beautifully! Excellent. I tried it both with the MWE and the original (big-ish) file. Thank you very much. If you post a short answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s helpful comments ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673659/is-there-a-simple-fix-to-using-hypertarget-inside-thmtoolss-restatable?noredirect=1#comment1673904_673659), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673659/is-there-a-simple-fix-to-using-hypertarget-inside-thmtoolss-restatable?noredirect=1#comment1673923_673659)) the solution is to

> [S]urround the `\hypertarget` with wrappers `\ifthmt@thisistheone` and `\fi`.

Since this contains the character `@`, one must in turn add wrappers `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to surround the entire environment, in this case `restatable`.

So the pertinent change is:

```
\makeatletter %%% <--- added
\begin{restatable}[Made-Up theorem]{theorem}{MadeUpTheorem} 
    Made-up assumptions are listed here.
    \ifthmt@thisistheone{\hypertarget{thm: made-up-theorem-subpart}{}}\fi %%% <--- changed
    \[ X = 3AB \tag{*}\]
    This is a made-up theorem.
\end{restatable}
\makeatother %%% <--- added
```